# Swift: Casting UICollectionViewCell to Private Class type?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, iphone-privateapi

Through recursion, I have accessed a private collection view inside a child view controller. It contains cells of type `IceCreamCell` which hold a `coneImageURL` string.

The problem is I'm not sure how to cast the accessed UICollectionViewCell to `IceCreamCell` to access the `coneImageURL` property since the cell class is private and Xcode doesn't recognize it.

Is there a way I can define the type by string (e.g. `class(with name: "")` and or request that property in that manner?

EDIT: By private I mean that it's inside a private third party framework where I don't have access to the actual files.

Comment: You should be able to use value for key path.

Comment: You should look at [isKind(of:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobjectprotocol/1418511-iskind) and [NSClassFromString(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/1395135-nsclassfromstring). Not sure if the class string name will work, but here is an example of how I've used it. `let tabBarButtons = self.tabBar.subviews.filter({ $0.isKind(of: NSClassFromString("UITabBarButton")!) })`